# How can I in spatie/laravel-medialibrary to keep info about youtube key?

Tags: laravel, youtube, laravel-medialibrary

In laravel 8 app using spatie/laravel-medialibrary 9 for storing of images and videos in adminarea I also use youtube keys
(only key, not url) which can be attached for some item. If there is a way to store youtube key im media table of laravel-medialibrary
and have one common model both for media files uploaded by user and by youtube key ?